# How can I properly rewrite the following if statement to a conditional statement? Using a multiplication compound assignment operator

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm attempting to rewrite the following if statement as a conditional statement.

```
if (hours > 40)
  wages *= 1.5;
else
  wages *= 1;
```

Here is my attempt that works, but I don't think I used the multiplication compound assignment operator correctly or at all.

```
int hours = 50, wages = 20;
System.out.println("Wages = " + (hours > 40 ? wages * 1.5: wages * 1));
```

Comment: [Your current ternary expression already seems to work](https://rextester.com/TOY3946).  What is your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I believe he wants to multiply the `wages` variable with another value depending on a certain condition all in one line. At least that's what I understood from the question.

Comment: Always use curly braces on if statements, or else you risk a global security nightmare: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/curly-braces/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want to do is multiply the `wages` variable with either `1.5` or `1` depending on this condition `hours > 40` the following should work for you:

```
    int hours = 50, wages = 20;

    wages *= hours > 40 ? 1.5 : 1;

    System.out.println("Wages = " + wages);
```

**Output**

```
Wages = 30
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wages *= hours > 40 ? 1.5 : 1;
```